# How can I change the position of HTML inputs with a grid layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, css-grid

I have 4 Html inputs, in each line two. My problem is now: I can´t change the position of all of these inputs. The Css part looks so:

```
.calculator-menu-container {
    background-color: #1b1b23;
    width: 725px;
    height: 150px;
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    margin: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
    grid-template-rows: 75px 75px;
    gap: 0px 225px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.mint-price-input > input {
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    background-color: #1b1b23;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

.quantity-input > input {
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    background-color: #1b1b23;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

.gas-limit-input > input {
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    background-color: #1b1b23;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

.custom-interval-input > input {
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    background-color: #1b1b23;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

This is the Html part for the inputs:

```
<div class="calculator-menu">
        <div class="calculator-menu-container">
            <div class="mint-price-input">
                <h2>Mint Price</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Eth">
            </div>
            <div class="quantity-input">
                <h2>Quantity</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Units of Tokens">
            </div> 
            <div class="gas-limit-input">
                <h2>Gas Limit</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Units of Gas">
            </div>
            <div class="custom-interval-input">
                <h2>Custom Interval</h2>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my output looks so:
[image]
I don´t know now how can I move these 4 inputs more at the top from the container with the white border. What can I do? Have anyone an idea?

I searched already in the internet and tryed much things like "position" and much more. But anything wouldn´t worked.

Comment: Can you add your HTML too?

Comment: Without HTML we can't help; please - as asked - post your relevant "*[mcve]*" code, because without that information this question will be closed because we don't have enough information.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry, I added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `position: absolute` and `top bottom ...` properties then use `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to move vertically

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to remove the `postion:absolute;` , `top:` , `bottom:` CSS properties.
2. As you have mentioned you need to display 4 input boxes in 2 rows containing 2 each, so you need to club them in separate `<div>` tags along with their respective headings.
3. You need to change the height of the `<div>` tag that contains all the other tags within it. (I would suggest using relative CSS units like 'em' or 'rem' which will help in scalability.)

I have attached my version of code with some changes. You can refer to it.

```css
body {
    background-color: #1b1b23;
}
.calculator-menu-container {
    background-color: #1b1b23;
    width: 40rem;
    height: 20rem;
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr) ;
    gap: 5rem;
    color: #fff;
}

.calculator-menu-container h2 {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
}


.calculator-menu-container input {
    border: #fff solid 2px;
    background-color: #1b1b23;
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="calculator-menu">
        <div class="calculator-menu-container">
        <div>
            <div class="mint-price-input">
                <h2>Mint Price</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Eth">
            </div>
            <div class="quantity-input">
                <h2>Quantity</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Units of Tokens">
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="gas-limit-input">
                <h2>Gas Limit</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Units of Gas">
            </div>
            <div class="custom-interval-input">
                <h2>Custom Interval</h2>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
```